# Can the __set and __get methods behave differently inside and outside of a class?

Tags: php, oop, session

I'm playing around with OOP in PHP and am trying to write a basic Session class which will create a Session array.  When instantiating the class, the user will provide the first dimension of the array, and then I'd like them to be able to add any variable/value combinations to that Session.  As an example:

```
$session = new My_Session('testing');
$session ->boy = 'girl';
```

should be equivalent to typing `$_SESSION['testing']['boy'] = 'girl'`;

I thought that I could use PHP's magic `__set` and `__get` methods, but my output is not what is expected.  Below I have my class, an example, and my results:

The Class:

```
    class My_Session {
    function __construct($session_namespace) {

    $this->session_namespace = $session_namespace;
}


     public function __set($name, $value) {

   $_SESSION[$this->session_namespace][$name] = $value;


     }

     public function __get($name){

         return $name;


        }
}
```

The test:

```
$session = new My_Session('testing');
$session ->boy = 'girl';
$session ->cow = 'blah';

print_r($_SESSION);

$session2 = new My_Session('testing2');
$session2 ->boy = 'girl2';
$session2 ->cow = 'blah2';

print_r($_SESSION);
```

The funky results:

```
  Array
(
    [session_namespace] => Array
        (
            [session_namespace] => testing
            [boy] => girl
            [cow] => blah
        )

)
Array
(
    [session_namespace] => Array
        (
            [session_namespace] => testing2
            [boy] => girl2
            [cow] => blah2
        )

)
```

What I imagine is happening is that my __set and __get methods are being defined the same way outside of the class, as well as inside the class; is there anyway to avoid this so that I can keep the `$session->boy = 'girl'` syntax for the user instantiating the class, but at the same time, have `$this->session_namespace = $session_namespace` behave correctly inside the class (i.e. if I didn't have custom `__get` and `__set` functions)?

Thanks so much!

Comment: The edit you just made completely invalidates your question, since declaring the $session_namespace explicitly is actually the solution to your problem. I have rolled back the edit, and will explain why this solves it ain am answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magic __get and __set methods are only called when accessing a property which has not been explicitly declared. The reason your code is working as shown is that $session_namespace is just another undeclared property, so setting it calls __set, regardless of where that call is made.

What you need to do, therefore, is add a line declaring that property to your class definition such as `private $session_namespace` (it doesn't matter if it's public, protected, or private, but the general rule is to restrict things first, and relax the restrictions only when needed).

PHP will see the declared property, set it as a normal variable, and not call __set, while any other name will still call the magic methods. As a bonus, a private or protected variable will be considered to not exist when called from a public context, so it should even be possible to set $_SESSION['testing']['session_namespace'] if you for some reason wanted to.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  And your explanation makes sense, and gives me a better understanding of both methods.  @John, I still appreciated your initial response. :)